# Legendrian knots on pages of a compatible open book

Tags: 3-manifolds, contact-geometry

Suppose we have a Legendrian knot embedded on a page of an open book compatible with the given contact structure on the 3-manifold. Is it true that the page framing and Thurston-Bennequin framing of the knot are equal?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is true, since the tangent distribution to the pages and the contact planes can be made arbitrarily close, therefore they're isotopic along $L$.